# Possible to use 4G SIM to a 3G Pocket WiFi?

Tags: modem, 3g

I have [SoftBank C01HW Pocket WiFi / Huawei D25HW](http://mb.softbank.jp/en/products/data_com/images/c01hw_ph_main.jpg)) which as far as I understand is a 3G device.

I am wondering if a 4G SIM would work for this device as I'm planning to subscribe to [this local service in our country](http://www.wi-tribe.ph/) (yes, I live in the Philippines). Looking at the site, I can't really be sure if it could work.

PS: And to be honest, 4Mbps for a 4G is not really much of a difference in a 3G - especially if I only plan to get 2Mbps as the plan.